# Geometrical series with 9

Tags: elementary-number-theory

You have this infinite sum:

$\frac{1}{9} + \frac{1}{99} + \frac{1}{999} + \frac{1}{9999} + ...$

Take a truncated sum (just $n$ terms) and consider the numbers on the right side of the point.

Which is the minimum base (like 2 for binary, 10 for decimal, etc.) to whose system these cyphers could belong? For example, if there were just 0's and 1's in all truncated sums, it would be base 2.

Is this base less than 10? Is there a minimum number of terms after which all partial sums are just base 10? How looks the function that maps n (as number of terms) to b in [2, 9] as base? Has it any patterns?

P.S. Do I really need to have to $n = 2*3*4*5*6*7*8*9$ terms to see the first 9? And then what happens?

Thanks for the support!

Comment: It's base, rather than basis. A basis is something different.

Comment: It's basically the same.

Comment: I don't see how. Maybe you can give some explanation. Are we both on the same page here? I'm talking about this: 'A basis of a vector space V is defined as a subset $v_1,...,v_n$ of vectors in V that are linearly independent and vector space span V.'

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson Hi George, thanks for the correction. Relax, it was a joke :) {base, basis, basically} . Where ended the british humour? Not in Bristol, lukslaik. And please stop javac#-ing, a britishman should master (monthy) python as a rule. May the spirit bless you more and more! The father and the son did their job already and I wouldn't bother them any more, lukslaik. :D

Comment: I honestly didn't know it was a joke, although the thought did cross my mind, I must admit. I don't javac anymore. I've dabbled with Eclipse recently, more than once, which was a very bad move. I'm not a joker, since a man of God must be sober, but that doesn't mean I don't laugh: laughter does good like medicine and joy is a fruit of The Spirit, or part of the fruit of the Spirit. As for The Father, remember this:'For you did not receive the spirit of bondage again to fear, but you received the Spirit of adoption by whom we cry out, “Abba, Father.”' (Romans 8.15).

Comment: @George I like more the newlivingtranslation: 'So you should not be like cowering, fearful slaves. You should behave instead like God's very own children, adopted into his family -- calling him "Father, dear Father." '. My dad is a clown, his name is Laius, and likes to be laughed at. Because he has a dad of his own also. I take seriously just moms, it's fun to argue with them till they take out all their witch powers. Jocasta rules.

Comment: lol... not liking that translation as it doesn't mention the Spirit and allows the sense that we're not even really adopted.

Comment: I did not like much "bondage", it sounds a too pervert  word for the bible.

Comment: lol. What about 'sexual immorality', 'adulterers and fornicators' or 'strange flesh'?

Comment: yeah, ehehe, children should read the bible instead of watching porn nowadays, they would learn much more technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is no carry, the digit at the $n$th decimal place of $\frac 19+\frac1{99}+\ldots +\frac1{\underbrace{99\cdots 9}_k}$is the number of divisors of $n$ that are $\le k$.
Especially, for $k\le 9$ no digit $>k$ appears, but $k$ itself does appear (the first time at $\operatorname{lcm}(1,2\ldots,k)$), so with $k=9$ the first $9$ occurs at the $2520$th place.

It is in principle thinkable that due to carries no digit $9$ appears for some $k>9$.
And indeed this is the case with $k=10$ (because $2520$ is already a multiple of $10$).